# Command line: program freezes, starts again with user input

Tags: command-line, freeze, python3, c++, camera

I am running a c++ programm on ubuntu, which periodically executes python scripts for long time measurement purposes. My programm takes a photo every 10 seconds and then evaluates the data.

But after a random amount of time (without the pc going into sleep mode) from 30min to up to 12h the python3 script for taking a photo just freezes. When moving the mouse it resumes to run and everything works fine again for 30min to 12h.

I already wrote a script moving the mouse in circles every 10 seconds, but the program still freezes and resumes to work, when real user input (i.e. moving the mouse by hand) is provided.

Do you guys have any idea what could cause this? I am a beginner with ubuntu and have not seen behaviour like this before...